# What is the URL of the bookmarks or favorites section in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I need to add my bookmarks window to the main page. For that, it asks me for a URL which I don't know what it is. I know that the URL for the history list is `chrome://history`.

I tried with the PC or desktop's `chrome://bookmarks`, but it didn't work.

What is the URL of bookmarks or favorites

Answer (score 6):

There is no such URL for Chrome for Android as of version 80.0. All Chrome specific URLs are listed and can be accessed from `chrome://chrome-urls`. Bookmarks related URL is not listed there.

Second, for a user to access their Bookmarks a separate activity is launched named `org.chromium.chrome.browser.bookmarks.BookmarkActivity`, but this activity cannot be launched outside of Chrome.

In short, what you are after and specifically in the manner you are after is not possible on Chrome for Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set the home page URL, try this one (works fine for me in Android 11 Chrome):

chrome-native://bookmarks/

This will directly open your bookmarks when you launch Chrome (i.e. if there isn't already a tab open).